# cannot using Toast function inside class?

Tags: java, android

I have tried to show a message By using the Toast function In different formats I have served many parameters Like : `getBaseContext()`, `getContext()`,.`getApplication()`,`Context()`
But in the end there are mistakes and he did not succeed in showing a message

//My logCat:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.android.login, PID: 9911
                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                          at com.example.android.login.retrieveUserLogin$1.onResponse(retrieveUserLogin.java:76)                                                                      at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallback$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:86                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My class:

```
public class retrieveUserLogin {

    public Activity activity;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private HttpApi api;
    public int value_array;
    private List<Users> user;
    private String UserAccount_;
    private Call<HttpApi.HttpBinResponse> call;
    private Call<List<Users>> getUsersCall;
    private List<Integer>collection;
 //   private Context context;
      Context mContext;
    public retrieveUserLogin(final String t1 ,final String t2){

      //  context = context;
        api = HttpApi.getInstance();
        api.addHeader("Authorization","MyT23");
        getUsersCall = api.getService().getAllChatRooms();
        getUsersCall.enqueue(new retrofit.Callback<List<Users>>(){
            String UserAccuent;
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<List<Users>>response, Retrofit retrofit){

                collection = new ArrayList<>();
                user = response.body();

                String [] arrayString = new String[user.size()];
                String [] arrayString2 = new String[user.size()];

                int[] arrayInt = new int[user.size()];

                for(int i=0; i<response.body().size(); i++){
                    arrayString[i] = user.get(i).user_name;
                    arrayString2[i] = user.get(i).email;
                    arrayInt[i] =  user.get(i).password;

                    if(Arrays.asList(arrayString2).contains(t1)){
                        UserAccuent =   arrayString[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }

                boolean Check = Arrays.asList(arrayString2).contains(t1);
                boolean Check2 = contains(arrayInt , Integer.parseInt(t2));

                if(Check == true && Check2 == true){

               Toast.makeText(activity.getApplication(),"تم تسجيل الدخول يا......" +UserAccuent.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "sdfasd"+5, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else{
                 Toast.makeText(activity.getBaseContext(),"خطأ فى اسم البريد او كلمة السر" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                // Toast.makeText(getContext(),"XXX" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }});
    }


    public static boolean contains(int[] arr,int item) {
        for (int n : arr){
            if (item == n){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



    // End ;
}
```

Comment: You are getting no context in this class.
You have to send Context using class constructor.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The logcat you pasted isn't helpful. Please add it as full logcat which crash starts from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Call from Activity

```
retrieveUserLogin("username","userpassword",Activity.this)
```

//Change in Constructor

```
  public retrieveUserLogin(final String t1 ,final String t2, final Context context){
         mContext = context;  
        Toast.makeText(mContext ,"خطأ فى اسم البريد او كلمة السر" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

In your non-activity class

```
public class NonActivity {

public void showToast(Context context, String message){
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your constractor from `public retrieveUserLogin(final String t1 ,final String t2){` to `public retrieveUserLogin(Context context, final String t1 ,final String t2){`
and assign `mContext=context`, then pass your activity instance to it.

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT** store activities and contexts in fields. Instead pass them as parameters to the method.

```
public void retrieveUserLogin(
    final Context context, 
    final String t1 ,final String t2) {
    // ...
    // then change your toasts to
    Toast.makeText(context, "...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The problem was probably that you did not assign a value to `activity`, but passing context as a parameter solves that issue. That way, you can only call the method if you have a context to give it.

Answer (score 0):

Toast does not show any message because the activity is null:

```
Toast.makeText(activity.getApplication(),"تم تسجيل الدخول يا......" +UserAccuent.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

That is also why you are seeing a NullPointerException in LogCat.

You need to initialize the activity of retrieveUserLogin class:

```
public Activity activity;
```

inside the class constructor, and probably you will need to change your constructor a bit by adding one more parameter:

```
public retrieveUserLogin(Activity activity, final String t1 ,final String t2){
     // init activity here
     this.activity = activity;
     // your code
}
```